# Installing Azure Backup Server Crash With Error 4387

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

I am trying to install azure backup server on windows server 2016 to backup local sql server

the installation wizard pass requirement check

[image]

but when i  enter sql server instance name the wizard crash
[image]

i checked the error log and i found the error
but it is not usefull

```
* Exception : Invoking Watson with Exception:  => System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to get machine name information
   at Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.Utils.FqMachineName.GetDpmMachineName()
   at Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.Setup.Inspect.InspectHelper.CheckIfLocalMachine(String sqlServerName)
   at Microsoft.Internal.EnterpriseStorage.Dls.Setup.Wizard.VenusSQLInspectPage.sqlServerInstanceTextBox_LeavingBox(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLeave(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.UpdateFocusedControl()
```

what could be possible problem?
the server is not domain controller and it is not a member of any domain , 
just a bare metal server somewhere in cloud

Comment: Can you specify the SQL server hostname instead of using localhost?

Comment: @NancyXiong i did , it doesn't make any diffrence, i get the same error.

Comment: Can you have a try [this1](https://charbelnemnom.com/2016/12/an-unexpected-error-occurred-during-dpm-2016-installation-id-4387-sysctr-scdpm/) and [this2](https://www.avianwaves.com/Blog/ArticleID/199/dpm-2016-sql-2016-and-an-unexpected-error-occurred-during-the-installation-id-4387)?

Comment: @Arash Are you still finding any issue?

Comment: @SumanthMarigowda-MSFT . yes . we didnt continue with azure backup because of the issue .

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5316a59f-b71e-4619-9bda-b3a5dd6293fe/microsoft-azure-backup-setup-crashes?forum=windowsazureonlinebackup

Answer (score 0):

Just installed and overcame this error myself. Machine must be a member of an Active Directory & Domain for this to work. The answer is as you have outlined.

Goes back to a simple question, why would you not need to be connected to a domain in the first place. You could detach it, but it goes against the functionality provided.